# Why does unit test fail on first run?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, castle-windsor

I have 7 unit tests which fail when I run all tests from Solution level or from the test runner, but, when I run the tests from project level or from the project within the test runner they succeed.

I am trying to test that I can resolve an item from a Castle Windsor container once they have been installed.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Having_installed_the_request_processors
{
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<RequestProcessorInstaller>());
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        ((WindsorContainer)this._container).Dispose();
        _container = null;
    }

    [Test]
    public void can_resolve_the_job_status_request_processor()
    {
        Assert.That(_container.Resolve<IJobStatusRequestProcessor>(), Is.Not.Null);
    }
}
```

This is the error returned:

> SetUp : Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException : Could not convert string 'Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration.Log4netFactory,Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration,Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' to a type. Assembly was not found. Make sure it was deployed and the name was not mistyped.

As far as I can see the code in my test project is the same as my production code (which appears to function as expected).

Do you see any issues with the above?
Why does the test succeed in the aforementioned way?

Comment: It seems like when you run it different ways it is running from different directories that have different assemblies available. Not sure how to test that theory though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that this was due to the way in which the projects in the solution referenced each other, by changing the direction of some references it resolved the issue - thank you for looking